# Android: ContentObserver triggering more number of times

Tags: android

I have written an app to listen for SMS sent from default messaging app.

When I used the following code, the app was not triggering for SMS sent.

```
    SMSSentObserver smsSentObserver = new SMSSentObserver(null, this);
    ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
    contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), true, smsSentObserver);
```

then by using the following code, ContentObserver is getting triggered.

```
    SMSSentObserver smsSentObserver = new SMSSentObserver(null, this);
    ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
    contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"), true, smsSentObserver);
```

I was able to listen for the sms sent, but SMSSentObserver (implements ContentObserver) onCreate() method is called more than one time. 
Then I added conditions to the code to find out the sent sms event. But the conditions get passed by two events.

```
    public class SMSSentObserver extends ContentObserver {
        private final Context _context;

        public SMSSentObserver(Handler handler, Context context) {
            super(null);
            _context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            saveSentSMS();
            super.onChange(selfChange);
        }

        private void saveSentSMS() {
            Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
            Cursor cur = this._context.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);

            if(null == cur) {
                return;
            }

            if(cur.moveToFirst()) {
                String strProtocol = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("protocol"));
                if(null != strProtocol) { //for sent messages protocol will be null.
                    return;
                }

                int type = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("type"));
                if(type == 2) {
                    String strSMSBody = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body"));
                    String strPhoneNo = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
                    long smsDateTime = cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex("date"));
                    String serviceCenter = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("service_center"));
                    String strStatus = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("status"));
                    String strPerson = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("person"));
                    Log.e("Info", "SMS saved");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

"SMS saved" is displayed two times in the catlog instead of one time. Can someone please tell me, is there a any other way to find out the sent SMS?
Any help is Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common issue. I have tried several other ways and finally came up with a solution.

ContentObserver's onChange() is triggered three times in my case for outgoing sms. 
I see that you have tried using the type -> cur.getColumnIndex("type"). The type can be either 6, 4 or 2. In my case Out of the three times the event was triggered, two times I got type 2. It seems unreliable. Also there is uncertainty whether this would be the same in all devices.
I solved this by checking the messageID using smsCursor.getString(msgIndex). Store this in SharedPreference. Next time when the event triggers compare the old messageID with the new one. Extract the content only if the ID is different. This way you can avoid the duplicates.